# Edit, Insert, Update mode for ASP.NET user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, user-controls, web-user-controls

I am looking for the best way to template a user control, so that when I specify a mode say readonly, edit, update, insert then the user control changes its mode correspondingly.

I have identified some methods and what I am looking for is a much elegant solution.

- Create a form view in the page and specify insert, edit template as
  separate user control and load accordingly.
- Create a form view inside user control and specify separate controls
  for edit/ insert for the records.
- *Find a way to template the user control so that when I specify the
  mode, when init ing a user control it will load appropriately into
  the page.*

  ```
  <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:FormView  DefaultMode="ReadOnly" ID="FormView1" runat="server"> 
      <ItemTemplate>
      <name:user ID="User1" Visible="true"  runat="server" />
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
       <name:user ID="User2" Visible="true"  runat="server" />
      </EditItemTemplate>
  </asp:FormView>
  ```

Please share your views on how this is done in normal scenarios; with just one user control and user control changing state based on Mode( a single user control and not 3 user controls for functions).

Comment: You could use a query string `?mode=insert` and read that from the usercontrol, then switch modes accordingly

Comment: @DGibbs thanks. In that way, I will have to layout all (Controls) edit/insert readonly into the controls and switch accordingly. Is there anyway, in which based on user control, say it will load the correct controls without extra markup?

Comment: Only other way would be to separate the modes into different user controls and hide/show on the parent page based on the mode.

Comment: @DGibbs I understand your point, I was thinking in similar lines to EditTemplates in FormView, which will load the edit template, my understanding was that it will load the edit controls automatically. I think I am wrong in that and so may be I need same user control with separate logic for user control edit/insert/update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use MultiView ASP.NET control. You can simply set up different views of your content and switch between these views whenever you like.

Here is some tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YV5w7sgojm0

Comment: thanks. I will try to create insert/update/ readonly views and switch accordingly.